# ASP.Net MVC 5 plugins how to programmatically import and export parts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins

how to create plugins with MEF that can be Turn on,off, install, and uninstall from an Admin setting page.

Answer (score 0):

I just move the plugin(dll) turned off in another dir. 
Install and Unistall is a simple "copy plugin" or "delete plugin"

Comment: NO is no tlike that i want to create project  dasbord with my own plugins when the client want this plugins just i installed for him    is not the plugins of mvc